# Optimal way of writing an IF statement

Tags: jquery

Im having a hard time understanding the limits and possibilities of an IF statement. I just want to know the best and shortest way to write following. Essentially I just want to return false if an input is empty or if textarea still contains its default value. This form is name, email, phone and comments where phone is optional so I cant just target all inputs.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if ( $('#email').val() == '') {
        return false;
    } else if ($('#name').val() == '') { 
        return false;
    } else if ($('textarea').val() === 'Enter comments here.') {
        return false;
    }
});
```

This code works, but it takes up a bunch of space. Thanks!

Comment: How do you remember each control's default value? (new ``placeholder` attribute, use a `data` attribute, etc.?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine your conditions into a single logical statement, like this:

```
return !(($('#email').val() == '') 
     || ($('#name').val() == '') 
     || ($('textarea').val() === 'Enter comments here.'));
```

The bang symbol (!) is a NOT; it reverses the logic, returning false if any of the conditions succeed, and true if none of them succeed.

Comment: <strike>Um, I think the logic is reversed from what OP wants.</strike> Fixed, I see. It might be more readable to `return $('#email').val() != '' && $('#name').val() != '' && $('textarea').val() !== 'Enter comments here.')`

Comment: Right you are... Good exercise for the OP.

Comment: Wasnt exactly what I asked for, but it is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with this one-liner:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if ( $('#email').val() == '' || $('#name').val() == '' || $('textarea').val() === 'Enter comments here.') return false;
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

"Best" and "shortest" are not necessarily the same. I believe the "best" solution is usually the most readable. Considering your example, you could use something like this (no `if` required):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var emailSet = $('#email').val() != '';
    var nameSet = $('#name').val() != '';
    var placeholderReplaced = $('textarea').val() !== 'Enter comments here.';
    return emailSet && nameSet && placeholderReplaced;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
if ( $('#email').val() == '' || $('#name').val() == '' || $('textarea').val() === 'Enter comments here.') {
    return false;
} });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
return !$('#email').val() 
       || !$('#name').val() 
       || $('textarea').val() !== 'Enter comments here.';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    var checkValue = function (selector, value) {
        return $(selector).val() == value;
    };

    return checkValue("#email", "") 
        && checkValue("#name", "") 
        && checkValue("textarea", "Enter comments here.");
});
```

As already mentioned, you should probably think more on readability and maintainability of your code rather than just size.